# Arrays are null. Not getting information from while loop

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, java.util.scanner

The following snippet of code is supposed to read from a text file, check how many words are in the file, and how many lines there are, and with that information it's supports to sort the nth word into it's appropriate array.

```
 protected static void loadAccountInformationFromFile() throws Exception 
    {
        // These variables control the logic needed to put words in the right array
        int accountNumberCount = 1;
        int firstNameCount = 2;
        int lastNameCount = 3;
        int balanceCount = 4;
        int lastVariableCount = 5;
        int sortCount = 1;


        Scanner account = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_ACCOUNT_FILE)).useDelimiter(",");

        // Using word count to get the nth value later
        int wordCount = 0;
        while(account.hasNext())
        {
            account.next();
            wordCount++;
        }

        // If the count is zero it means the account list is empty
        if (wordCount == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("error: Account list empty."); 
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Used to test word count feature:
//       System.out.println("Number of words: " + wordCount);

        int lineCount = wordCount / MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE;

        // These arrays will be used to put the account information in the correct place
        // Using the lineCount to create the Array of however large it needs to be
        String[] accountNumber = new String[lineCount - 1];
        String[] firstName = new String[lineCount - 1];
        String[] lastName = new String[lineCount - 1];
        String[] balance = new String[lineCount - 1];
        String[] lastVariable = new String[lineCount - 1];


        // If I don't close and open a new Scanner I get a compiler error       
        account.close();                
        Scanner account2 = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_ACCOUNT_FILE)).useDelimiter(",");

        do
            {

                String[] temp1 = account2.next().split(",");
                String temp2 = "" + temp1;

                if (sortCount == accountNumberCount)
                {
                    accountNumber[sortCount] = temp2;
                }
                if (sortCount == firstNameCount)
                {
                    firstName[sortCount] = temp2;
                }
                if (sortCount == lastNameCount)
                {
                    lastName[sortCount] = temp2;
                }
                if (sortCount == balanceCount)
                {
                    balance[sortCount] = temp2;
                }
                if (sortCount == lastVariableCount)
                {
                    lastVariable[sortCount] = temp2;
                }

                accountNumberCount += 5;
                firstNameCount += 5;
                lastNameCount += 5;
                balanceCount += 5;
                lastVariableCount += 5;

                sortCount++;

                {

                }

            }
        while (account2.hasNext()); 

        // testing to see if it works, but it only returns:
        // [null, [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302, null, null, null]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(accountNumber));

        // This one only returns [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302
        System.out.println(accountNumber[1]);

        account2.close();
 }
```

It has no problem opening the file and counting the words properly. However, when it came time to put the words into the appropriate array it doesn't work, as indicated in the commenting out text.

My question is: Why? And how can I get this to work properly without using BufferedWriter / BufferedReader?

---

Based on an answer, I corrected a flaw in the logic only to end up with

run:
error: 6
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Here's the modified code:

```
 public class Main 
 {
private final static int ACCOUNT_NUMBER_INDEX = 0;
private final static int FIRST_INDEX = 1;
private final static int LAST_INDEX = 2;
private final static int BALANCE_INDEX = 3;
private final static int FREE_CHECKS_INDEX = 4;
private final static int INTEREST_INDEX = 4;
private final static int MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE = 5;
private final static String INPUT_ACCOUNT_FILE = "accountInfo.txt";
protected static String[] fields;

 protected static void loadAccountInformationFromFile() throws Exception 
    {
        // These variables control the logic needed to put words in the right array
        int accountNumberCount = 0;
        int firstNameCount = 1;
        int lastNameCount = 2;
        int balanceCount = 3;
        int lastVariableCount = 4;
        int sortCount = 1;


        Scanner account = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_ACCOUNT_FILE)).useDelimiter(",");

        // Using word count to get the nth value later
        int wordCount = 0;
        while(account.hasNext())
        {
            account.next();
            wordCount++;
        }

        // If the count is zero it means the account list is empty
        if (wordCount == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("error: Account list empty."); 
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Used to test word count feature:
 //                System.out.println("Number of words: " + wordCount);

        int lineCount = wordCount / MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE;

        // These arrays will be used to put the account information in the correct place
        // Using the lineCount to create the Array of however large it needs to be
        String[] accountNumber = new String[lineCount];
        String[] firstName = new String[lineCount];
        String[] lastName = new String[lineCount];
        String[] balance = new String[lineCount];
        String[] lastVariable = new String[lineCount];


        // If I don't close and open a new Scanner I get a compiler error       
        account.close();                
        Scanner account2 = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_ACCOUNT_FILE)).useDelimiter(",");

        do
            {

                String[] temp1 = account2.next().split(",");
                String temp2 = "" + temp1;

                if (sortCount == accountNumberCount)
                {
                    accountNumber[sortCount] = temp2;
                    accountNumberCount += MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE;
                }
                if (sortCount == firstNameCount)
                {
                    firstName[sortCount] = temp2;
                    firstNameCount += MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE;
                }
                if (sortCount == lastNameCount)
                {
                    lastName[sortCount] = temp2;
                    lastNameCount += MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE;
                }
                if (sortCount == balanceCount)
                {
                    balance[sortCount] = temp2;
                    balanceCount += MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE;
                }
                if (sortCount == lastVariableCount)
                {
                    lastVariable[sortCount] = temp2;
                    lastVariableCount += MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE;
                }

                sortCount++;

            }
        while (account2.hasNext()); 

        // testing to see if it works, but it only returns:
        // [null, [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302, null, null, null]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(accountNumber));

        // This one only returns [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302
        System.out.println(accountNumber[1]);

        account2.close();
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(accountNumber[1]);`?

Comment: Why do you not want to use BufferedWriter/ BufferedReader?

Comment: @immibis That is supposed to test to make sure that the class is being written to. It just outputs a given position of the array.

Comment: @LonelyIdiot Why does everything always ask that? When taking a college class the students are heavily restricted. I already know how to solve the problem with BufferedReader, but it's not allowed for this assignment.

Comment: @Elliander You never said that you were restricted. To us it seemed like this was a problem that shouldn't have existed.

Comment: @Elliander You misunderstand. Try using the code in my comment; notice the call to `Arrays.toString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because on every iteration of the loop, you increase all the count variables.

When coming to the loop for the first time you have the following variables:

```
accountNumberCount == 1
firstNameCount == 2
lastNameCount == 3
balanceCount == 4
lastVariableCount == 5
sortCount == 1
```

So `sortCount == accountNumberCount` and that means you put the word into `accountNumber` array to the second position (index starts from 0 on arrays).

Then you increase all the above variables and go for round two, having the following situation:

```
accountNumberCount == 6
firstNameCount == 7
lastNameCount == 8
balanceCount == 9
lastVariableCount == 10
sortCount == 2
```

Thus on second iteration `sortCount` no longer equals any of the other variables. Same thing happens on further iterations and you end up with only one word inserted into one of the five arrays.

---

If you want to make this work, I'd suggest using `ArrayLists` (so you don't have to worry about array indexes or array sizes) instead of arrays and to only change one variable per each iteration.

```
private static final int ACCOUNT_NUMBER_COUNT = 1;
private static final int FIRST_NAME_COUNT = 2;
private static final int LAST_NAME_COUNT = 3;
private static final int BALANCE_COUNT = 4;
private static final int LAST_VARIABLE_COUNT = 5;    

List<String> accountNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> balances = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> lastVariables = new ArrayList<String>();

int sortCount = 1;

// Other things...

do {
    if (sortCount == ACCOUNT_NUMBER_COUNT) {
        accountNumbers.add(temp2);
    } else if (sortCount == FIRST_NAME_COUNT) {
        firstNames.add(temp2);
    } else if (sortCount == LAST_NAME_COUNT) {
        lastNames.add(temp2);
    } else if (sortCount == BALANCE_COUNT) {
        balances.add(temp2);
    } else if (sortCount == LAST_VARIABLE_COUNT) {
        lastVariables.add(temp2);
    }

    if (sortCount < 5) {
        sortCount++;
    } else {
        sortCount = 1;
    }
} while (account2.hasNext());
```

Comment: hmm. I see your point. Even setting them to be 0 through it's all null. I would at least expect the first to store the value. I definitely see what you mean about the sortCount not matching, so I edited it to have the other variable counts increase only when they were used, but this just resulted in Error: 6. Your answer is definitely helpful and I can see that ArrayList would be better, but I would see like to understand why this approach won't work if possible. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: It's still doable, just needs more complex logic. You're still left with the error of putting things into the index of `sortCount`. So on first word is added to `firstName[1]`, then second word is added to `lastName[2]`, third word added to `balance[3]` and so on. Basically you need a different variable for the insert position.

Comment: You probably want first word to be added to `accountNumber[0]`, second to `firstName[0]` and so on. Thus, you can use something like `int insertPosition = sortCount / MAX_VALUES_PER_LINE`, since it will round down neatly to nearest integer. P.S. If the answer is definitely helpful, you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd read line by line using BufferedReader, that way you do not need to calculate the number of lines,

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       // process the line.
    }
}
```