# How to print actual data from list of objects?

Tags: java, list, hibernate

I need to Print actual value from below list of objects. Is this possible to get actual values from this list ?

```
try {

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select uName1,pass1 from UserRegModel");

        List<Object> userList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        userList = query.getResultList();

        System.out.println("selecting usernaem and pass done");

        for (Object temp : userList) {

            System.out.println(temp);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return userList;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I get below output. not the actual password and username

> Ljava.lang.Object;@2c36b22d

Comment: usr getters on the object to get the uname/passwd(recommended way) or override the `toString()` method to print them, when directly using object(not recommended)

Comment: Override `toString()` in the `UserRegModel` class and as a side note you should also use a more specific type than `Object` in the declared `List`. You manipulate list of `UserRegModel`. So declare : `List<UserRegModel>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to display contents of ArrayList. Getting \[Ljava.lang.String;@232204a1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900426/trying-to-display-contents-of-arraylist-getting-ljava-lang-string232204a1)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4